# DisableCors Not Working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have the following **WebApi C#** *Controller*:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
[EnableCors(origins: "http://pincopalli.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
  [Route("checkusername/{_username}")]
  [HttpGet]
  public bool CheckUsername(string _username)
  {
    try
    {
      using (BugMeEntities database = new BugMeEntities())
      {
          database.Database.Connection.Open();

          if (database.users.Where(x => x.name.Equals(_username)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  [Route("checkemail/{_email}")]
  [HttpGet]
  public bool CheckEmail(string _email)
  {
    try
    {
      using (BugMeEntities database = new BugMeEntities())
      {
          database.Database.Connection.Open();

          if (database.users.Where(x => x.email.Equals(_email)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  [DisableCors]
  [Route("register")]
  [HttpPost]
  public User.Response Register([FromBody]User.Register _user)
  {
    try
    {
      if(_user.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(_user)).Any(x => x != null))
      {
          using (BugMeEntities database = new BugMeEntities())
          {
              database.Database.Connection.Open();

              if(database.users.Where(x => x.name.Equals(_user.username)).Count() == 0)
              {
                  if (database.users.Where(x => x.email.Equals(_user.email)).Count() == 0)
                  {
                      string newPassword = randomPassword();

                      bool emailSent = Utility.newMail(_user.email, "Benvenuto su BugMe", $"Benvenuto <b>{_user.username}</b>,<br>La nuova password necessaria per accedere è: <b>{newPassword}</b>.");

                      if (emailSent)
                      {
                          users user = new users { name = _user.username, password = newPassword, email = _user.email, active = true };
                          database.users.Add(user);
                          database.SaveChanges();
                      }

                      return new User.Response { status = true, message = $"Congratulazioni, ti sei registrato con successo! \nAbbiamo inviato un'email a {_user.email} contenente la password necessaria per accedere." };
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      throw new ArgumentException("Email non disponibile.");
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  throw new ArgumentException("Username non disponibile.");
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("Compilare tutti i campi del form.");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      return new User.Response { status = false, message = ex.Message };
    }
  }

  [DisableCors]
  [Route("login")]
  [HttpPost]
  public User.Response Login([FromBody]User.Login _user)
  {
    try
    {
      if (_user.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(_user)).Any(x => x != null))
      {
          using (BugMeEntities database = new BugMeEntities())
          {
              database.Database.Connection.Open();

              users userFetch = database.users.Where(x => x.name.Equals(_user.username) && x.password.Equals(_user.password) && x.active.Equals(true)).FirstOrDefault();

              if (userFetch != null)
              {
                  User.Session user = new User.Session
                  {
                      id = userFetch.id,
                      username = userFetch.name,
                      password = userFetch.password,
                      email = userFetch.email
                  };

                  return new User.Response { status = true, message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user) };
              }
              else
              {
                  throw new ArgumentException("Utente non trovato.");
              }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("Compilare tutti i campi del form.");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      return new User.Response { status = false, message = ex.Message };
    }
  }

  private static string randomPassword(int lunghezza = 8)
  {
    const string caratteri = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ0123456789!$";
    string passsword = string.Empty;
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < lunghezza; i++)
    {
      char carattere = caratteri[random.Next(caratteri.Length)];

      if (random.Next(0, 2) == 1) { carattere = Char.ToLower(carattere); }

      passsword += carattere;
    }

    return passsword;
  }
}
```

and the **JqueryClient** *Register Call*:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: api_uri + 'users/register',
  data: JSON.stringify(_user),
  contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

I want to disable CORS Policy just for **register** and **login** web methods, so I added the *[DisableCors]* attribute to them.

I hosted the WebApi project on **IIS** (*localhost:82*) and the JqueryClient too (*localhost:83*).

When tried to call the **register** web method, I receveid an error of *CORS failed parameters*.

[image: Chrome Console Debugger Error]

Can someone help me resolve the problem?

Comment: Thank you. The issue is simply because you disabled CORS on the endpoint you're calling. You *need* to have it when making a cross domain request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i didn't understand your sentence... could you explain it more? Thank you.

Comment: `I want to disable CORS Policy just for register and login web methods, so I added the [DisableCors] attribute to them.` That is your problem. You cannot disable CORS if you're making a cross domain request.

Comment: Then... should i use another way to secure my client calls?

Comment: That depends on the security you want to have. However CORS *has* to be enabled for the request to work from JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you DisableCors then you won't be able to make cross domain call on that action. In case you want to secure your service from cross domain calls then use EnableCors with restricted domain. Like you already doing at controller level

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://pincopalli.com,http://localhost:83", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

This will allow calls only from http://pincopalli.com and http://localhost:83. Will reject calls from all other domain. Ex- http://localhost:84 or http://contoso.com etc..

This will secure your api from cross domain call originating from domains you don't trust. Hope this helps.

For more detail reading : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins